# How to set text view right of image view dynamically

Tags: android, dynamic, view, textview, imageview

I have a dynamic event view. In that I have image view and text view. I want to show image view in notification is not null and text view to the right of image view.

For this I have set visibility of image view as gone. So if notification is not null image view should be visible and text view should move to right of image view.

How to achieve this?

Event view layout :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/shape"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="15dp"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/notify"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
        android:background="@drawable/sound"
        android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="04dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="05dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
        android:layout_marginTop="01dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="05dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

event view code :

```
 private void createEvent(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup dayplanView, int fromMinutes, int toMinutes, String title,String location,final int id,int color,String notification) {

   eventView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.event_view, dayplanView, false);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) eventView.getLayoutParams();

    container = (RelativeLayout) eventView.findViewById(R.id.container);
    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) eventView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTitle);
    list.add(eventView);

    ImageView notify = (ImageView) eventView.findViewById(R.id.notify);


    ((GradientDrawable) eventView.getBackground()).setColor(color);

    tvTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));


    if (tvTitle.getParent() != null)
       ((ViewGroup) tvTitle.getParent()).removeView(tvTitle);

    if(notification == null)
    {

        notify.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        notify.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }


    if(location.equals(""))
    {
        tvTitle.setText("Event : " + title);
    } else {
        tvTitle.setText("Event : " + title + " (At : " + location +")");
    }
    int distance = (toMinutes - fromMinutes);
    layoutParams.topMargin = dpToPixels(fromMinutes + 9);
    layoutParams.height = dpToPixels(distance);

    eventView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    dayplanView.addView(eventView);
    container.addView(tvTitle);



    eventView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            i = new Intent(getActivity(), AddEventActivity.class);
            editMode = true;
            i.putExtra("EditMode", editMode);
            i.putExtra("id", id);
            startActivityForResult(i, 1);

        }
    });
}
```

Now the image view is shown above the text view. How to move text view right to image view if it is visible?

Comment: you dont need to set textview to right dynamically...see my bellow answer...accept and like it if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this attribute in your textview

```
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/notify"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
        ImageView notify = new ImageView(getContext());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) notify.getLayoutParams();
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.notify);
```